# Does this mean I need to tokenize my json first?

Tags: python

I'm trying to clean up some chat logs to do some data analysis on it and I'm really just grasping at strings on how to do this. As I'm trying to get rid of stopwords and converting the file to excel I get

> unhashable type: 'dict'

Here's my code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
import codecs

data = ""
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('Taglish')

with codecs.open("1207ChannelMess.json", 'r', 'utf8') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

for item in data:
    for key in item:
        if key == "title":
            temp = str(item[key]).lower()
            temp = re.sub('[`~!@#$^&*()\-_=+{};:\'",<.>/?\\|\[\]★]', '', temp)
            temp = ' '.join([word for word in temp.split() if word not in stopwords_list])
            item[key] = temp

with codecs.open('1207ChannelMess.json', 'w', 'utf8') as new_data_file:
    json.dump(data, new_data_file)

df = pd.read_json(codecs.open('1207ChannelMess.json','r','utf-8'))
df.to_excel('out.xlsx',{'remove_timezone': True})
```

Does this mean that the json file needs to be tokenized first? Any direction would help

Full Traceback

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-46-e84b9b575347> in <module>
     23 
     24 df = pd.read_json(codecs.open('1207ChannelMess.json','r','utf-8'))
---> 25 df.to_excel('out.xlsx',{'remove_timezone': True})
     26 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)    
   2254         startcol=startcol,    
   2255             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
-> 2256             engine=engine,    
   2257         )    
   2258 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine)
    737             startrow=startrow,
    738             startcol=startcol,
--> 739             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
    740         )
    741         if need_save:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlsxwriter.py in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
    201         sheet_name = self._get_sheet_name(sheet_name)
    202 
--> 203         if sheet_name in self.sheets:
    204             wks = self.sheets[sheet_name]
    205         else:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Please post the _full_ traceback

Comment: Have you looked at the to_excel function? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html